# Sheaf of sections of $S^1$ double covering is not isomorphic to etale sheaf of $S^1$ double covering

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-theory, covering-spaces

This is an example of Rotman Homological Algebra 5.72 (2).

$S^1\subset C$ is unit circle where $C$ is complex plane. Let $p:S^1\to S^1$ be $p:z\to z^2$ and let $\operatorname{dom}(p)=E, \operatorname{codom}(p)=X$. It is clear that $X$ has a double cover sitting above through $E\to X$ projection by $p$. It is clear that stalks of $E$ are isomorphic to $Z_2$ abelian groups. Furthermore $E$ is Etale sheaf over $X$. It is clear that sheaf of sections has same stalks as $E$.

How do I see sheaf of sections $\Gamma(-,E)$ of $E$ not isomorphic to $E$?

---

The book is saying $\Gamma(-,E)$ is not isomorphic to constant $Z_2$ sheaf over $X$. This is clear.

Comment: Why are the stalks isomorphic as $\mathbb Z_2$ abelian groups? They consist of two elements, sure, but is there a canonical way to consider them as a group? Just pick the element with positive $y$ coordinate as the identity element? What about continuity of addition then?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** : $ \Gamma(E,E)$ contains the identity element and also the map which switch the two points in the fiber, on the other hand $E$ considered as Etale-sheaf over $X$ has no global sections as it would gives a section of the map $z \mapsto z^2$.

Comment: It is clear there is no global section on $X$ to $E$ due to $X$ compact. What do you mean by $\Gamma(E,E)$? Only $\Gamma(X,E)$ is an object in $Sh(X,Ab)$ category. How would you switch two points of fiber or even identity element?(i.e Let $\sigma\in\Gamma(X,E)$, $p\circ \sigma =1_X$ is also satisfied.)